# how to add new data to all child in firebase database by one click using javascript and html

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add new data to all child in firebase database by one click using javascript and HTML

my database

```
  "User" : {
"dfdlg" : {
  "name" : "vinay"
},
"dgfhsg" : {
  "name" : "singh"
},
"fgdfk" : {
  "name" : "test"
}
}
```

I need to add age to all user. like below

```
"User" : {
"fjhsgfjsh" : {
  "age" : 19,
  "name" : "vinay"
}
}
```

what code I am doing in javascript

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you already tried? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write data to a node, you must know the complete path to that node. Since you don't know those yet here, you'll need to first load the data, and then update each child.

In JavaScript:

```
firebase.database().ref('User').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
    userSnapshot.ref.update({ age: 42 });
  })
});
```

Comment: thanks bro .its work